# Looking for a file-diff tool which allows URL's as input

Tags: properties, diff

I'm looking for a file diff tool which allows me to enter URL's to properties files stored on a web server) rather than local files - all the tools I've tried (WinMerge, Diffuse, Beyond Compare) seem to only allow local files (or files on a server) to be compared.

In other words, be able to directly compare http://www.example.com/releases/14F/base.properties and http://www.example.com/releases/14G/base.properties simply by passing those two URL's to the file diff utility.

To make this more complicated, I'd really like this to be something that can be used by techies and non-techies alike - it may need to be used by e.g. Product Managers... Sure, I could use cURL to GET the file and then pass it to one of the tools I mentioned above, but my PM's will neither have cURL installed nor want to use it.

It doesn't matter to me whether it's an actual executable or a web-based service, but if it's an executable, it needs to work on a PC and ideally also on a Mac.

If it allows the comparison of more than two files, that's great - right now we use Diffuse, which can compare at least 10 files at the same time, but that's not a requirement - being able to compare files by providing their URL would be more useful than being able to compare 10 files all of which need to be downloaded from the web server.

Does anyone have any experience with any tools which enable this? If this can't be done directly, something useful which will enable me (or the non-techies mentioned above) to in as few steps as possible, retrieve those files and compare them - something simpler than "Right-click to view source, save as .txt file to desktop etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firefox and "[Page Diff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4274)" plugin

Description: Page Diff  is an add-on that helps web developers and designers see HTML source code differences between web pages. This is helpful for finding code irregularities or differences that will enable you to debug rendering issues.

Here is an example output

[image: PageDiff plugin example output]

Comment: Great suggestion -- it's cross platform, okay for non-technicals, and doesn't require you to share data with third parties (not listed as a requirement, but I'd consider it a big plus).

Comment: This IS a great tool, but it's only for Firefox. That might be a problem, but currently, it's looking like the best option, since it will do diffs on both local files and URL's.

Comment: Actually, since you can enter ANY file path, you can also do diffs on any file type, not just HTML. So it's the winner...

Answer (score 6):

Use `diff`

```
diff <(curl http://google.com) <(curl http://yahoo.com)
```

Comment: Granted this solution might not be suitable for non-technicals or for  Windows.

Comment: An obvious solution, but unfortunately, as I said, this needs to work on Windows.

Comment: I should've read your question more carefully before answering. Still, I'll leave the answer here as it may be helpful to someone who is simply "Looking for a file-diff tool which allows URL's as input."

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to ECMerge (for which I work), it supports HTTP/HTTPS URL for files. It works on Windows and Mac (and Linux as well).

Comment: I downloaded ECMerge and tried it out, but I suspect the cost would be a factor I couldn't get round. Nevertheless, it does look like a great product, and if we had the cash to pay for it for the 50-odd people who might use it, it would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another great online tool is [Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/editor).

It supports files as well as URLs. It has a very nice UI and you can save or share your diff results.

Here's [an example](http://www.mergely.com/AaKBFTmz/).

Answer (score -1):

You say you are using Diffuse which is apparently written in Python.  So I assume that means they have Python installed already?  So why not write a simple script in Python that downloads both files and then calls Diffuse?

```py
import urllib, sys, os

urllib.urlretrieve(sys.argv[1], "first")
urllib.urlretrieve(sys.argv[2], "second")
print "Comparing %s to %s:" % (sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])
os.system("diffuse first second")
```

Comment: The fact that we USE a tool written in Python doesn't mean we all have Python installed. It's downloadable as a .exe, after all.

Comment: Does that really deserve a -1 though?  I know it doesn't necessarily mean that, there were a lot of other suggestions you didn't like, so I thought I would see if this was a possibility.

Comment: Hey Jason, you're right. That was a bit harsh of me. I was trying to make it clear that I have to get something that works for techies like myself and non-techies. So being told "write a Python script" bugged me on many different levels - partly because I don't have Pythin installed (although I once did), partly because that obviously wouldn't work for users that didn't have Python installed and so on. On reflection, I'm removing my downvote. UPDATE: I can't remove the downvote unless you edit your answer... Go to it.